Is there a way to rename wp-env generated docker container names?
I'm quite new to docker and am working on a wordpress page with a development setup based on wp-env.
While container names show up in Docker Desktop with generated ids, this becomes quite confusing if there are a lot of containers listed in there and i always have to search for the right one to start.
Example of containers w/ cryptic names in docker :

So I was wondering if there is a way to rename them to more readable names, (e.g. my-project-name) or can I add any config entry while generating them?

this my .wp-env config:

{
  "plugins": [
    "./plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro",
    "./plugins/disable-comments", 
    "./plugins/updraftplus"
  ],
  "themes": ["./my_custom_theme"],
  "config": {
    "WP_DEBUG": true,
    "WP_DEBUG_LOG": false,
    "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY": true,
    "SCRIPT_DEBUG": true
  }
}


renaming in /.wp-env folder had no effect.

terminal >  docker rename 9b0e712e5cb3e62ae48945a702424b20 wp_some_custom_name
had no effect.


Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
